# Does the Bouncy Castle RSAKeyGenerationPerameters publicExponent have to be positive?

Tags: java, exception, encryption, rsa, bouncycastle

I am attempting to make a **partially blind signature program**. I was planning on using the **price of a product** as the piece of **common information for the key generation**. The code shown below produces an exception "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: public exponent cannot be even".

However, **when using an odd number the code runs perfectly fine**.

Why must this number be positive and is there a workaround, for example adding some sort of padding function rather than just adding 1 if it is positive?

```
// Generate a 2048-bit RSA key pair.
    public static AsymmetricCipherKeyPair generateKeyPair() {
        
        RSAKeyPairGenerator generator = new RSAKeyPairGenerator();
        
        // Initialise the key pair generator
        // TODO: Change so that the common information is the product price
        generator.init(new RSAKeyGenerationParameters(
                    new BigInteger("10000", 16), new SecureRandom(), 2048,
                    80));
        
        // return an AsymmetricCipherKeyPair containing the generated keys.
        return generator.generateKeyPair();
    }
```

Comment: The public exponent has to be a prime number and even numbers by definition are not prime. In addition, there are few other considerations. Please refer to this excellent post: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/22437/rsa-public-key-exponent-generation-confusion

Comment: @Ironluca: The public exponent does *not* have to be prime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The public **modulus** `n` of an RSA key is the product of two odd primes `p` and `q`. Its [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) `phi(n)` is `(p - 1) * (q - 1)`, hence it is even.

The basis of the [RSA algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) is that if two numbers `a` and `b` are equal modulus `phi(n)` than `x^a` and `x^b` are equal modulus `n`.

Now we would like the **public** exponent `e` and the **private** exponent `d` such that `d * e` is equal to `1` modulus `phi(n)`. That's only possible if `e` and `phi(n)` are [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers). Since `phi(n)` is even, `e` must be **odd**.

Moreover usually on takes `e` with the smallest number of `1` bits possible, so the exponentiation function is faster. Since `e` cannot be even and should not be one, one takes something of the form `2^r + 1`, with `r` usually `16`.

**Edit**: Sorry, I missed your question about `e` positivity. In short it **can not be negative**. If you provide a negative exponent you'll get:

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: BigInteger: modulus not positive
```

during key pair generation.